# SDL2 Segfaults - Implementing a renderer

Tags: sdl, game-engine, renderer

Just implemented a SDL_Renderer in my engine

```c
state_t init_rend(window_t *context,flag_t flags) {
        rend.renderer = NULL;
        rend.renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(context,-1,flags);
        rend.index = -1;

        if (rend.renderer != NULL) {
                return TRUE;
        } else {
                return FALSE;
        }
}
```

In my client/test app:

```c
 // Init Base2D game
        init_env(VIDEO|AUDIO);

        // Init Display display
        init_disp(640,480,"Display",RESIZABLE|VISIBLE,make_color(255,255,255,255));

        // Init Renderer renderer
        init_rend(display->window,SOFTWARE);

        // Game Loop
        state_t status;
        while (TRUE) {
                update();
                status = listen();
                if (!status) {
                        break;
                }
                /* User Event Handles */
        }
```

And I could handle window resizing successfully with:

```c
void resize_window() {
        printf("I was here!\n");
        SDL_FreeSurface(display->container);
        printf("Now I am here\n");
        display->container = SDL_GetWindowSurface(display->window);
        SDL_FillRect(
                display->container,
                NULL,
                SDL_MapRGBA(
                        display->container->format,
                        get_red(),
                        get_green(),
                        get_blue(),
                        get_alpha()
                )
        );
}
```

However, since I have implemented the renderer, whenever I attempt to resize my display it segfaults when trying to `SDL_FreeSurface(display->container)`.

As I have mentioned, the resizing worked fine until I implemented a renderer.

Why is this happening?

Comment: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowSurface **Do not free this surface.** ... **You may not combine this with 3D or the rendering API on this window.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the link provided by user:keltar,

It seems to me the way to go with SDL2 is to use a renderer for drawing to the window intead of the old SDL1 method of using a surface.

I did just that, removed the `surface` code and used a renderer only and the code works without problem

Thank You